# AutoCompleteTextView showing no data

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview

I am trying to populate data from an **SQLite** table but the autocomplete does not seem to show any suggestions.

When I check the ArrayList it has the required data. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

**The AutoCompleteTextView code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mybusapp.BusRoutes" >


   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="@string/auto_complete"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <AutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Function that returns the data **

```
public ArrayList<String> getByRoutes1()
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BUSROUTE + " ORDER BY 1 DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
          try {

                 // looping through all rows and adding to list
               if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                   while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                          items.add(cursor.getString(1));
                          cursor.moveToNext();
                        }
                 }
            } finally {
                    try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }


        // return route list
        return items;

    }
```

**Activity Class code**

```
private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    DBHelper dbHandler = new DBHelper(this, null, null, 1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_routes);
        ArrayList<String> values =  dbHandler.getByRoutes1();  // The values populate here

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, values);
         actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
         actv.setThreshold(1);
         actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If I use the below array it seems to populate correctly.  I just replace "values" with "COUNTRIES".

```
 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

**EDIT1**

The data returned by the getByRoutes1 function is like this:

> [31, 46, null, null, S64, 114, 121, 64C, 164, 38A]

I think the **null** could be causing an issue

**EDIT2**

The issue was with null data being returned.  I changed the function name to something more readable.

```
public ArrayList<String> getByRoutesFilter()
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BUSROUTE + " WHERE routeno is not null ORDER BY 1 DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
          try {

                 // looping through all rows and adding to list
               if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                   while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                          items.add(cursor.getString(1));
                          cursor.moveToNext();
                        }
                 }
            } finally {
                    try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }


        // return route list
        return items;

    }
```

Comment: check the returned value of your `getByRoutes1`

Comment: Updated my question.  I think the issue maybe with some null data

Comment: add some condition in where clause ... `where country is not null`

Comment: it was the issue with the null field

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code its working for me

```
  edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);



    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sightstitle.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(sightimages[i], sightstitle[i],sightimagearow[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            adapter.filter(s.toString().trim());
        }
     });

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();


}
```

Comment: Actually it was an issue with null data being returned, but thanks anyway